# vscode or sublime extension to find and jump to Nth match within a text file

Tags: text-search, sublime-text, visual-studio-code

I would like a software/extension that could support:

1. find all occurance of specific text (supporting regular expression);
2. based on result of 1st step, quickly goto/jumpto the nth occurance.

Comment: What operating system? Linux? Is console-base OK?

Comment: HI Nocolas, actually I would prefer a vscode or sublime extension. I could write an external python script, which is not so direct and requires operation outside.

Comment: I would love that for Eclipse & Notepad++ I might even raise a new question to ask :-)